# fs.write file is only writing into a file when node index.js is executed. When pkg is run as a CLI, it does not write

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fs, file-writing

I am building a CLI using Node. I am using the `fs` module `writeFile` method. Every time I run CLI through `node index.js`, I can write into the file. But when I run it as a CLI, `fs.writeFile` does not write.

```
fs.writeFile("./utils/auth.js", userToken, (err) => {});
fs.writeFile("./utils/user.js", userData, (err) => {});
```

Comment: For starters, add logging of any error rather than silently eating the error.  `fs.writeFile("./utils/auth.js", userToken, (err) => { console.log(err)});`  One can imagine that the working directory might be different so perhaps `./utils` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: FYI, we have no idea what "run it as a CLI" means so perhaps you can show and example of what that means.